Data on prisoner swap deals
I am looking for data on prisoner-swap deals in recent years. What I currently found is:

Israeli-Arab prisoner exchanges;
Arab-Byzantine prisoner exchanges (less relevant - from over 1000 years ago);
10 notable prisoner exchanges, mostly involving USA citizens.

I am looking for a more comprehensive list - one that would include, for example, the recent Ukraine-Russia POW exchanges.
Is there such a list?

This data is hard to find because of the sensitive and often classified nature of many hostage negotiations - especially between the US and terror organizations. Recall, for example, in 2016 the Obama administration secretly flew a plane of $400 million in cash followed by two further shipments totalling an additional $1.3 billion in Swiss francs and euros  to Iran under the cover of darkness to secure the release of Americans held hostage by Tehran. In all likelihood this would have remained secret, but was exposed when  Iranian state-run media televised the cash being delivered by plane.

You might also try to see if the data you are looking for is contained in the Uppsala Conflict Data Program (UCDP) datasets or the Correlates of War (COW) project datasets, which might have relevant conflict-related data that includes prisoner exchanges.

I didn't DV this, but a reason why you won't find such stats easily is the Q is nebulous due to whom you want to include in the scope. E.g. the recent swap between Iran and some EU countries involves nominally convicted people. While POWs swaps between Russia and Ukraine are another matter, legally speaking. Also, do population exchanges like those between India and Pakistan count? (Or the Armenians from N-K, to pick something more recent.) Etc.
